# How could I process the data of a csv file in python?

Tags: python, numpy, csv

I have a csv file. I need to iterate over each row accessing specific fields per row and use that data in the next stage.

Was thinking of using some numpy load csv method.

Comment: It depends on how you want to manipulate the csv. For data analysis, a popular module is [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
pip install csv
```

```
with open('my-csv-file.csv', newline='') as csvFile:
    csvData = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    for row in csvData:
        print(', '.join(row))
```

Comment: `csv` is a built-in module, no need for `pip install`.

Answer (score 0):

## Loading CSV using NumPy

Numpy does offer a functionality for this. It's called [np.loadtxt](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html).

```py
import numpy as np
 
# using loadtxt()
arr = np.loadtxt("sample_data.csv",
                 delimiter=",", dtype=str)
display(arr)
```

## Loading CSV into an array using Python's `csv` library

Python offers a [csv library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) for this as well.

```py
import csv
with open('sample_data.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        print(', '.join(row))
```

## Loading CSV using built-in Python

Alternatively you don't actually need to use a third-party library. CSV is simply a text file with comma-separated values. Knowing this you can use the Python built in method to parse it.

```py
with open("data.csv") as data:
    for line in data:
        items = [item for item in line.split(",")]
        print(items)
```

Answer (score 0):

The most popular library for tabular data handling is pandas

Sample data -

```
csv = '''"Header1", "Header2"
"Replace", 100
"string", 200
"with", 300
"file location", 400
"or url", 500'''
```

Code to only import one column -

```
import pandas
data = pandas.read_csv(csv, headers=["header1"]
```

printing data gives a table like

```
|"Header1"       |
|----------------|
|"Replace"       |
|"string"        |
|"with"          |
|"file location" |
|"or url"        |
```

More info here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html